# How to specify the generic type of a funcion call in jsdoc when parameters can't infer type

Tags: javascript, generics, jsdoc

I'm trying to use JSDoc for typings, and i came across this scenario (this is a simplified example).

We can use @template for generics, and parameters can make it infer the type of return like this example on the docs

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {T} x - A generic parameter that flows through to the return type
 * @returns {T}
 */
function id(x) {
  return x;
}
 
const a = id("string");
const b = id(123);
const c = id({});
```

But what about when parameters don't use the template

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {String} str 
 * @returns {T}
 */
function parse(str) {
  return JSON.parse(str)
}

const x = parse('{}')
```

Notice how it says any as the return type

[image: function]

I know that i can use @type on x and call it a day `/** @type Type */ const x = ...`, but i was wondering if you can tell what type to use, like what you can do on Typescript

`const x = parse<Type>('{}');`